# Pythond docx кодировка

Tags: python, python-docx

Задача была такая что нужно заменить в док файле значения {{fio}},{{idn}} на реальную фамилию и ИИН с помощью python-docx. Код который заменяет это работает:

```py
document = Document('files/doc1.docx')
fio = "Иванов"
idn = "92929292929929"
# первый уровень
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            # второй уровень
            if '{{idn}}' in run.text:
                text = run.text.split('{{idn}}')
                run.text = text[0]+ idn + text[1]
            if '{{fio}}' in run.text:
                text = run.text.split('{{fio}}')
                run.text = text[0]+ fio + text[1]

... work with doc
```

Ошибка тут в том что во втором уровне, указанный в коде, кириллица превращается в `"\xd0\x98\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2"` что-то вроде такого, но на первом уровне она норм выводит кириллицу. На уровнях проверял через `print()`
Ошибка такая:

```
(util.py:65 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "ValueError occurred, args=('All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters',)
```

Пробовал такие варианты как снизу, но результат такой же, ошибка

```py
fio.decode('utf-8')
fio.encode('utf-8')
```

Помогите, что можно сделать ещё?

Comment: `fio.decode('koi8-r')` ?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не сработало(

Comment: `fio.decode('cp1251')` ?